# core-plot graph title shadow?

Tags: ios, macos, core-plot

As with adding a shadow to plot's data label, how does one add it to the graph title?  This line doesn't work:

```
CPTMutableShadow * shadow = [CPTMutableShadow shadow];
shadow.shadowColor = [CPTColor blackColor];//colorAtIndex:slot.backRGB];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,-1);
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2.0f;
graph.titleTextStyle.<?> = shadow;
```

I guess what's needed along with the examples is a recipe book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set a shadow only on the graph title.

You can use a layer annotation instead of the title. Use a `CPTTextLayer` as the annotation content layer and set the shadow on that. All `CPTLayer` objects have a `shadow` property.

Comment: Can you elaborate, example?  I see how plot context data labels are provided via an annotation object but not seeing how this is done at the graph (affecting all plots) context ?

Comment: Ah, ok; I would do similar to bar plot data labels but for a title; thanks.